# Existence of prime elements in an atomic integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-factorization, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain, is it true that if $R$ is atomic, then it must contain a prime element?

If not, what is a counterexample?

I know that if an element is prime, then if $I$ is the ideal generated by it, then $R/I$ must be an integral domain. However, $R$ being an atomic integral domain doesn't really help for that, since even if we take the ideal generated by an irreducible element $a,$ there can still be nonunique factorizations of $ka=rs$ such that $r$ and $s$ are not multiples of $a.$

I'm stuck on how to approach the problem in other ways and I can't really get a sense of if it's even true or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You should provide some context to your question. Where is this problem from? Why is it interesting and important? Please tell in the post, did you try to solve it? What progress did you achieve? Where were you “stuck”?

Comment: If $R$ is atomic but not a UFD and $S$ is the multiplicative subset of $R$ consisting of the elements that have a factorization into prime (not merely irreducible) elements, then one could form the localization $S^{-1}R$ to "get rid of" all the prime elements.

Comment: More generally, if $P$ is any set of irreducible elements in an atomic domain $R$, then one could localize $R$ at the multiplicative subset generated by $P$ to "get rid of" the irreducible elements in $P$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang You have to be a bit careful, as localizing could, in principle, remove more irreducibles, or turn some into primes. E.g., in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, inverting just the powers of the irreducible $2$ will destroy the irreducibility of $3$, as now we have that an associate of $3$ (namely $6=2\times 3$, and $2$ is now a unit) equals $(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$, neither one a unit. But I think inverting *prime elements* won't change non-prime irreducibles into reducibles.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang However, inverting too much may turn some irreducibles into primes. A Dedekind domain with only finitely many prime ideals is a PID, so if you took $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and inverted all prime elements and irreducibles other than $2$, $3$, $1+\sqrt{-5}$ and $1-\sqrt{-5}$, you get a PID, so now irreducibles are prime.